# How to rename each dataframe as stock name from yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

stock_list = ['TSLA','DDOG','NET','MSFT','AAPL']
df_list=[]
for stock in stock_list:
    str(stock)_df = yf.download(stock, '2020-01-01')
    df_list  = df_list.append(df)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give more details about your problem and full error messages if any. So we can reproduce and help more easily.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is exactly supposed to do, but what I see is:

```
df_list=[]
for stock in stock_list:
    ...
    df_list  = df_list.append(df)
```

The .append() method returns None, thus assigning None to df_list in the loop is a source of errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a list, but it is easier to add the stock name and link the data frame together.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

stock_list = ['TSLA','DDOG','NET','MSFT','AAPL']
df_list= pd.DataFrame()
for stock in stock_list:
    df = yf.download(stock, '2020-03-01')
    df['stock'] = stock
    df_list = pd.concat([df_list, df], axis=0)

df_list.head()

    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume  stock
Date                            
2020-03-02  142.251999  148.738007  137.334000  148.723999  148.723999  100975000   TSLA
2020-03-03  161.000000  161.395996  143.222000  149.102005  149.102005  128920000   TSLA
2020-03-04  152.792007  153.304001  144.945999  149.899994  149.899994  75245000    TSLA
2020-03-05  144.753998  149.149994  143.613998  144.908005  144.908005  54263500    TSLA
2020-03-06  138.000000  141.399994  136.854004  140.695999  140.695999  63314500    TSLA
```