# Cannot get a file to be read into a list of stock tickers and then get yfinance data for each

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I am trying to read a csv file into a dataframe and then iterate over each ticker to get some yahoo finance data, but I struggle with matching the right data type read from the CSV file. The problem is that yfinance needs a str for the ticker parameter   `data = yf.download("AAPL', start ="2019-01-01", end="2022-04-20")`
and I cannot convert the df row item into str.

This is my code:

```
combined = yf.download("SPY", start ="2019-01-01", end="2019-01-02")
  

for index, row in stockslist.iterrows():
            
    data = yf.download([index,row["ticker"].to_string], start ="2019-01-01", end="2022-04-20")
```

and this is the csv file

[image]

The question is basically about this part of the code " [index,row["ticker"].to_string] " . I cannot get to pass each row of the dataframe as a ticker argument to finance.
The error I get is "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object "

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The image is the stockslist ? What is stockslist .. a data frame containing what exactly? Why are you including the index value in the yf.download command ? Enclosing an object in [] turns it into a list, not a single string value. I don't think that is what you want. What is the error that you receive ? There is an answer here about how to iterate over rows in a dataframe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: Your question is not very understandable, you could complete it with an example of your DataFrame and the expected result.

Comment: The question is basically about this part of the code " [index,row["ticker"].to_string] " . I cannot get to pass each row of the dataframe as a ticker argument to finance. The error I get is "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object "

Comment: Examples of my past [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780359/how-to-rename-each-dataframe-as-stock-name-from-yfinance/66781340#66781340) would be helpful. Prepare an empty data frame and get the data by retrieving the stocks from a list of stocks. Add a column for the name of the issue and add it to the first data frame you prepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `download` function doesn't understand `[index,row["ticker"].to_string]` parameter. Like where does it come from ?

you have to give the context of it. Like building an array with the values from the CSV then you pass the `array[i].value` to the `download` function.

A quick example with fictional code :

```
#initiate the array with the ticker list
array_ticker = ['APPL''MSFT''...'] 

#reads array + download
for i=0 in range(array_ticker.size):      
     data = yf.download(array_ticker[i], start ="2019-01-01", end="2022-04-20")
     i=i+1
```

---

UPDATE :

If you want to keep the dataframe as you are using now, I just did a simple code to help you to sort your issue :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'ticker': ['APPL', 'MSFT', 'GAV']}
ticker_list = pd.DataFrame(data=d) #creating the dataframe
print(ticker_list) #print the whole dataframe
print('--------')
print(ticker_list.iloc[1]['ticker']) #print the 2nd value of the column ticker
```

Same topic : [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)